# convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I'm reading a paper, for proving a claim it defines $$ f_n(x) = \dfrac{(rx-x^2)^n}{n!} $$ when $ r = \frac{a}{b} $ is a rational, and $ I_n = \int^r_0 f_n(x) \cdot \sin x \cdot dx $ , and then it says when $ n \to \infty $ we have $ b^n I_n \to 0 $.

But I can't understand why. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it is $n \rightarrow \infty$ while the domain $[0, r]$ stays finite. Moreover, $rx - x^2 = x(r - x)$, so the maximum of  the function $f_n(x)$ occurs at $r/2$ (the midpoint). Thus,
$$b^n f_n(x) \leq b^n\frac{(r^2/2 - r^2/4)^n}{n!} = \frac{b^n r^{2n}}{4^n n!} \rightarrow 0.$$
We can thus bound the integrand times $b^n$ by $\epsilon/r$ for sufficiently large $n$, so that
$$b^n |I_n| \leq \int_0^r |f_n|b^n dx < \frac{\epsilon}{r} \int_0^r dx = \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $b^n  I_n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_0 ^r (ax - bx^2)^n \sin(x)$ As sin is bounded, $|b^n  I_n |\leq \int_0^r \frac{|(ax - bx^2)^n|}{n!} dx$. That term is equivalent to $ (-b)^n \frac{r^{2n+1}}{2n*n!}$ which goes to 0 because of $n!$